# Paypal IPN - detect if payment was unsuccessful due to insufficient funds

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Is there a way in IPN to detect if the transaction was unsuccessful due to insufficient funds? I can't get it to work on sandbox somehow. It still continues to accept the payment even if my buyer has not enough funds. I think it is related to credit card but i can't seem to remove the last credit attached to the account. So i really want to test my app using a buyer with insufficient funds so i can be sure that i can trap transactions like that. I am using paypal rest api in php and IPN for this. As much as possible, i don't want to add another or any sorts to achieve this because Paypal is really to hard to understand.

Comment: Is it really any of your business? It could have been lack of funds, expiry, cancellation of the CC, ... What's important for your business is that you didn't receive the payment that was due. Why is his problem, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

Best place to check your 'listener' is with the IPN Simulator here https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/ (after you log into your PayPal Sandbox account).

You can test all sorts of payments there.